# Youtube iFrame does not load on Phonegap Build Android App

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build

I created a phonegap build mobile app which is supposed to be on windows, android and ios. But I have been struggling with an issue for like three days now.

On my videos page, I load youtube videos via iframe and i have tested on windows which works perfectly. On android, all i see is just an empty box(not black) in the space that is supposed to be occupied by the video. Youtube is whitelisted in my config.xml thus:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<access origin="http://www.youtube.com"/>
<access origin="https://www.youtube.com"/>
```

Any help will be appreciated.